# How to make a CLUSTERING ORDER BY date and an IN at the same time?

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

I am working on a social networking project with a post system.

Here is my current post table

```
CREATE TABLE afterstr.posts (
    user_id text,
    date timeuuid,
    content text,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, date)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date DESC)
```

Here is the user follow table in which I retrieve a list of the user's subscriptions.
It is with this list that I will retrieve the last post of the user's subscriptions.

```
CREATE TABLE afterstr.follows (
    from_id text,
    to_id text,
    followed_at timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (from_id, to_id)
)
```

there is also a users_infos table which contains all the information about the user but which we do not need here.

My problem is that users can make multiple posts.

example of the table posts with a

> SELECT * FROM posts;

```
920022 | a5cf4950-d46a-11ec-a4e5-19251c2b96e1 (19/03/2022) |      Thank you for the new sub !!!
920022 | a5cf4950-d46a-11ec-a4e5-190382029828 (16/03/2022) |      meeting tomorow
920022 | a5cf4950-d46a-11ec-a4e5-19251c2b96e1 (28/02/2022) |      I will orgenise a meeting during the next moth 
234235440 | a5cf4950-d46a-11ec-a4e5-190382029828 (23/03/2022) |     Hey !!!
234235440 | a5cf4950-d46a-11ec-a4e5-190382029828 (21/03/2022) |      See you later
992777    | a5cf4950-d46a-11ec-a4e5-202093838892 (22/03/2022) |      Hey
```

In the context of loading a feed by date of publication, I would like to retrieve the posts of two people with whom the user is subscribed to in our case the user '234235440' and the user '992777'. And retrieve them according to the publication date of their post with a limit of 3.

Here is the select command:

> SELECT * FROM posts where user_id in ('234235440', '992777') limit 3;

but cassandra does not send me the last 3 posts of all users but only the last 2 of the first id in the "IN" without sorting by date.

Cassandra responce (the numbers 1, 2 and 3 are the contents and represent the order of sending):

```
234235440 | a5cf4950-d46a-11ec-a4e5-19251c2b96e1 (23/03/2022) |      Hey every one 
234235440 | a5cf4950-d46a-11ec-a4e5-190382029828 (21/03/2022) |      See you later
992777    | a5cf4950-d46a-11ec-a4e5-202093838892 (22/03/2022) |      Hey
```

Here is the expected answer

```
234235440 | a5cf4950-d46a-11ec-a4e5-19251c2b96e1 (23/03/2022) |      Hey every one 
992777    | a5cf4950-d46a-11ec-a4e5-202093838892 (22/03/2022) |      Hey
234235440 | a5cf4950-d46a-11ec-a4e5-190382029828 (21/03/2022) |      See you later
```

My aim is to make a feed based on a user's subscription. So the goal is to get the last 3 posts from the list of people he is subscribed to. My problem is that for the moment Cassandra returns me only the 3 last post of only one user (tier by date) without taking into account the dates of publication of posts of other person to who he is subscribed which are more recent.

Do you have any idea how to solve the problem by avoiding ORDER BY which is not recommended for this type of request ? Do you think that the use of a search engine could be an optimised solution?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra guarantees order only inside the single partition, but not between partitions. When you specify multiple values for partition key, then it will take data from first partition, sorted only inside it, then from second partition, again sorted only inside it, etc. If you need to have a global order, you need to sort yourself.

Comment: Would using a common key partition for all lines be a more optimized solution?

Comment: In your case it wont help, as sorting happens by date column, not by content column

Comment: I realise I asked the wrong question, I have reworded the post to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

The column `content` is not even part of the clustering columns in first place to get the results sorted. Rest of the working is as explained by Alex earlier.

```
token@cqlsh:astra1> select user_id,toTimestamp(date),content from astra1.posts;

 user_id   | system.totimestamp(date)        | content
-----------+---------------------------------+---------
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:41:54.283000+0000 |       3
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:41:25.721000+0000 |       1
    992777 | 2022-05-15 17:41:35.414000+0000 |       2

(3 rows)
```

In the above result, as you can see within the given partition key column of `user_id`, the result of clustering column `date` is already sorted by default how we wanted it to sort (i.e. `date DESC`).

If I had wanted the results by `ASC` sort order, then I could do something like below:

```
token@cqlsh:astra1> select user_id,toTimestamp(date),content from astra1.posts where user_id='234235440' order by date asc;

 user_id   | system.totimestamp(date)        | content
-----------+---------------------------------+---------
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:41:25.721000+0000 |       1
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:41:54.283000+0000 |       3

(2 rows)
```

---

Let's say if I've the below data in my table for `user_id = 234235440`,

```
token@cqlsh:astra1> select user_id,toTimestamp(date),content from astra1.posts where user_id='234235440' order by date asc;

 user_id   | system.totimestamp(date)        | content
-----------+---------------------------------+---------
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:51:50.351000+0000 |       1
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:51:53.130000+0000 |       2
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:51:55.802000+0000 |       3
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:51:58.261000+0000 |       4
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:52:00.751000+0000 |       5
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:52:03.717000+0000 |       6

(6 rows)
```

and if I want only the top 3 sorted by the clustering order which I've already defined while creating the table, I could leverage `PER PARTITION LIMIT` to fetch only the top 3 for that given partition column,

```
token@cqlsh:astra1> select user_id,toTimestamp(date),content from astra1.posts where user_id='234235440' per partition limit 3;

 user_id   | system.totimestamp(date)        | content
-----------+---------------------------------+---------
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:52:03.717000+0000 |       6
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:52:00.751000+0000 |       5
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:51:58.261000+0000 |       4

(3 rows)
```

remember that I could also reverse the clustering column sorting order and fetch the top 3 in the reverse direction like this:

```
token@cqlsh:astra1> select user_id,toTimestamp(date),content from astra1.posts where user_id='234235440' order by date asc per partition limit 3;
 user_id   | system.totimestamp(date)        | content
-----------+---------------------------------+---------
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:51:50.351000+0000 |       1
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:51:53.130000+0000 |       2
 234235440 | 2022-05-15 17:51:55.802000+0000 |       3

(3 rows)
```

For example, if you want only up to the top 3 rows per partition across that table, your query would look like below:

```
token@cqlsh:astra1> select * from astra1.posts per partition limit 3;

 user_id   | date                                 | content
-----------+--------------------------------------+---------
 234235440 | ba85cb50-d477-11ec-b834-4dbc24fdf387 |       6
 234235440 | b8c137f0-d477-11ec-b834-4dbc24fdf387 |       5
 234235440 | b7454650-d477-11ec-b834-4dbc24fdf387 |       4
    992777 | 44065d60-d476-11ec-b834-4dbc24fdf387 |       2

(4 rows)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Madhaven I think I misspoke, my aim is to make a feed based on a user's subscription. So the goal is to get the last 3 posts from the list of people he is subscribed to. My problem is that for the moment Cassandra returns me only the 3 last post of only one user (tier by date) without taking into account the dates of publication of posts of other person to who he is subscribed which are more recent.

Comment: @Jasvar, your datamodel doesn't depict the full picture here. Where is the subscription and other details like the connection to users, etc.,? Remember that sorting is happening by the `clustering column` that you've defined in the table's schema. If you need it to sort based on other things, you would have to define them in the data model aka table schema.

Comment: I made an update of the question with hopefully all the information